# How can I change the frequency of the RAM, and also know its value from Ubuntu?

Tags: ram, macbook-pro, frequency, memtest

I am using two modules of RAM and I would like to know their frequency because at simple sight, I can't see any sign of it in the modules.

When I ran memtest one time, it showed me the test settings' values (some related to the RAM), but on subsequent runs it showed me another set of values; values which I don't understand because I haven't find a fair reasonable user guide. Furthermore, I cannot control the settings of memtest. The program, launched from grub's menu, does not respond to keystrokes in a Macbook Pro with dual boot (Mac OS and Natty-amd64-mac).

I would also like to know if the impossibility to control the program with the keyboard is normal in Mac computers? or I did something wrong during the installation?. Can I fix that?. Is it still like that in newer versions of Ubuntu?

Also: Is there a way to change the frequency of the RAM, like in the bios, in refit's shell or grub?

Comment: You can download a program such as AIDA64 it is a Windows software though, but works fine on Wine. Memtest is for testing RAM.

Comment: "Also: Is there a way to change the frequency of the RAM, like in the bios, in refit's shell or grub?"- Easiest way it's doing it from your BIOS, if yours support it, if not then I'm not sure if it can be done via software in Linux.

Comment: Thank you. But that program, AIDA64, what for? What question will it answer?. Does it run on Mac before booting?

Comment: You could try to plug in a USB keyboard and see if memtest reacts to that.

Answer (score 1):

See if your computer supports DMI, which usually has information about memory components (including speed):

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory
```

Comment: Thank you. That displays Speed: 667 MHz (1.5 ns). But what is that value talking about exactly?. What confuses me is that, AFAIK, a memory chip can work at different frequencies; Bios can change that. But in this Mac I don't know if it can be changed and how to check the frequency at which it is being used. I am asking this because the different values in different memtest runs made me think that something might be wrong or not properly configured

Comment: My understanding is that BIOS fills in the DMI information. I suppose an indication of "Speed" is the maximum, as there is a separate value called "Current Speed" (some computers I checked have the latter, others the former, none both). I wouldn't be terribly surprised if some BIOS presented incorrect values (or attribute names).

Answer (score 0):

I ran `dmidecode -t memory` with my 2400 MHz ram clocked at 1866 MHz in the BIOS:

```
Handle 0x0042, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x003F
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
        Bank Locator: BANK 1
        Type: DDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1867 MHz
        Manufacturer: 04CB
        Serial Number: 00000414
        Asset Tag: 9876543210
        Part Number: DDR3 2400 2OZ     
        Rank: 1
        Configured Clock Speed: 1867 MHz
```

So apparently it's the configured speed.